# How can I disable an unknown number of buttons and know which ones so I can enable only them again later?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, unobtrusive-validation

Hi I am trying to disable all buttons when the user submits so while the page is loading they can't submit again or do other actions. But the page might also already have disabled buttons so I can't simply do

```
$('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

then

```
$('.btn').removeAttr('disabled');
```

I will have to enable the buttons again if the form fails unobtrusive validation.

In twitter-bootstrap there's .button('loading') and .button('reset') but that replaces the button text with "loading" and I prefer them to be just disabled.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: My solution won't enable buttons that were disabled in a different sceneria, If it is disabled somehow because of some other functionality the other suggested solutions of enabling disabled buttons won't suite you. In my way you will enable only those buttons you've disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jQuery is *fluent*, the call for

```
$('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Returns an array of the changed items. You can store it like this:

```
var disabledBtns = $('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

**Update**

As you want to get only the buttons that are not already disabled, filter them like this:

```
var disabledBtns = $('.btn:not(:disabled)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

That way you're saving and disabling buttons that are enabled.

Comment: Doesn't that return the whole collection, and not just the ones that where actually changed ?

Comment: The thing is, that the entire collection was changed. You call the 'attr' function on a collection, it does it thing and returns that same collection.

Comment: Oh, I didn't take into account the buttons that are already disabled, I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 1):

Find the ones that are'nt already disabled, give them a class and disable them:

```
$('.btn').filter(function() {
   return !this.disabled;
}).addClass('disabled_now').prop('disabled', true);
```

to enable them again, you'd do :

```
$('.disabled_now').removeClass('disabled_now').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Gee, I did'nt remove the class, as I was thinking it was pretty much implied, but I'll add it to the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var $non_disabled_buttons = $('.btn').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is(':disabled');
}).attr('disabled', true);
```

Then to re-enable them :

```
$non_disabled_buttons.attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have merits, they use a variable to store the list of disabled objects.  This seems slightly inelegant to me, since the DOM can be modified at various times which could potentially invalidate things like control lists stored in JS variables.

My solution would be to apply a class to the buttons that you're disabling, and use that class in a jQuery selector when you want to enable them again.  Something like:

```
// disable buttons
$(':button').not('[disabled]').addClass("dis_temp").attr("disabled","disabled");

// do something
//...

// enable buttons disabled above
$('.dis_temp').attr("disabled", null).removeClass("dis_temp");
```

Using a DOM class to group objects seems to be fairly common practice.

In most situations I prefer to leave the buttons alone and go with a modal jQueryUI dialog.  It's a question of style I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery 1.6 and higher. You should use the `.prop()` method

```
$(".btn").prop('disabled', false);
$(".btn").prop('disabled', true);
```